# IB Custom UITableViewCell - Dynamic Height for cell and detailText

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

Im trying to create a table very similar to the Messages table,

It requires 3 labels,
- Title
- detailText 
- Time (on the far right side)

The detail text needs to be dynamic height and so does the actual tableViewCell

is it possible to make a dynamic height tableViewCell in IB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can,

Just use this method to of the UITableViewDelegate

```
tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need some [NSString method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893) to calculate the height of cell it needs. And in my experience, you need the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` as Cyprian said, and under different cell height, the cell returned from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should have different layout too, to present the multi-line strings.